# How to get a final URL after t.co redirects in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I know that I can generally get the current URL of WKWebView by using the URL property. However I have discovered that when there is a redirect, it will not give me the proper URL.

For example, if I go to http://twitter.com and then click on a link to some other company (ex: http://mycompany.com), then I see a t.co/XXX URL which eventually redirects me to mycompany.com.

However, when I look at WKWebView's URL property, I am seeing "t.co" instead of "mycompany.com".

Strangely, I am never seeing didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation:...  called, and when I check URL at didStartProvisionalNavigation:... and decidePolicyForNavigationAction:... I just see the "t.co" URL instead of the "mycompany.com" one.

Also, I will need to know the domain in order to make some adjustments to the body, so I am not sure if I can use JS here.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

UPDATE: I realized this only happens when I use a custom URL scheme set via setURLSchemeHandler:, which I had omitted from the question originally since I didn't think it was related.

After some playing around, I was able to get things working with the following change in willPerformHTTPRedirection:...:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = 
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:request.URL];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_webView loadRequest:newRequest];
});

 completionHandler(nil);
```

UPDATE: This has a serious drawback because URLs that are not for the main frame will come into willPerformHTTPRedirection:..., and if the request is re-loaded for all of these the page gets messed up.

I need a way to determine if the URL is from the main frame and only do the reload for those.

Comment: did you set its delegate? and try on the device. The simulator was acting odd sometime

Comment: Can you be specific about what delegate you mean? I am currently doing  _webView.navigationDelegate = self; _webView.UIDelegate = self;  and I am only testing on the device.

Comment: webview.navigationDelegate is sufficient. I did try and it works.

Comment: Here what i have tried:
`
if let url = URL(string: "https://t .co/periscopeproducer") {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    wkView.load(request)
    wkView.navigationDelegate = self
 }
`

`
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print(webView.url!)
    }
`
`
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print(webView.url!)
    }
`

Comment: I think if you start on the t.co URL it may act differently. Can you try starting the WKWebView on "https://twitter.com/microsoft" and then clicking on "news.microsoft.com" which leads to "https://t. co/bKBtZeAFrh"? My code is pretty much identical to yours, except I am doing this.

Comment: well, if you hover your mouse on the "twitter.com/microsoft", you should see the actual link is `https://t. co/bKBtZeAFrh`. So i tried with "https://t. co/bKBtZeAFrh`, it works.

Comment: Here what i got: https://imgur.com/a/uZ0IDUo

Comment: Thanks. But I think the flow is different if you start with the "twitter.com/microsoft" URL. Can you please try with that, click on the "news.microsoft.com" button (left side of page), and see what you get? I am working with a web browser, not a single request, so I have to handle flows like this.

Comment: I figured out. The reason is if you start off with "twitter.com/microsoft", it ends up redirecting you to "https://mobile.twitter.com/microsoft". And by inspecting that link https://imgur.com/a/57Odp5J, we can see that target="_blank", which prevents the webview from redirecting to "https://t .co/bKBtZeAFrh". Here is the result i got after  removing that target="_blank" attribute https://imgur.com/a/wF5KfqC.
So i guess what you can do is handle the onclick event, get the link, and have the webview load that new link

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so i made it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rclk0.jpg

The solution is to cancel the navigation and load the request with loadRequest: again.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame?.isMainFrame != true {
        webView.load(navigationAction.request)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Unfortunately in my case the "createWebViewWith" is never being called (I am using obj-C, though that shouldn't matter). Also, I removed target="_blank" and still get the issue. The problem actually is actually wider-reaching since not only is the URL wrong, but I see relative images are not loading properly since they are using the "t.co" domain instead of the proper one. So there is something funny going on during the redirect and I still cannot get the "microsoft.com" in any of the callbacks. I tried adding an auth callback but that has the same bad domain.

Comment: Make sure you set wkview.uiDelegate. Pretty weird

Comment: Sorry I had left in some code that was preventing the "createWebViewWith" from being called. I removed that and see it called now, but even after I add your code it doesn't help. I still only see "t.co" domain.

Comment: I don’t know what else you have done with the wkview. But If you create new project and put my code in, you should see it working.

Comment: Also, please use webView didFinishNagivation instead. I tested with didstartProvisionalNavigation and forgot to bring it back

Comment: I am using didFinishNavigation. After doing some more experimentation I got it to work with the twitter.com/microsoft. However if I try now with "https://twitter.com/twitter" and then click on "help.twitter.com" on the top left. I see all the URLs still say "c.to" instead of "help.twitter.com" and the rendering doesn't work well on the page.

Comment: After some more experimentation, the solution I mentioned isn't going to solve it because if I do the reload for all URLs passed into willPerformHTTPRedirection..., things get messed up. How can I how which redirects are for the main frame?